# Fetch Data from multi table datewise

Tags: mysql

Suppose:

Table Name : purchase

```
id          pur_Date        pur_value 
1           01/02/16        5000.00
2           02/02/16        2500.00
3           05/02/16        7000.00
```

Table Name : Sale

```
id          sale_Date       sale_value 
1           02/02/16        5050.00
2           02/02/16        2555.00
3           05/02/16        9000.00
4           05/02/16        7000.00
5           05/02/16        7250.00
```

Run a query...............

Result would like below:

```
Date            Value
01/02/16        5000.00
02/02/16        2500.00
02/02/16        5050.00
02/02/16        2555.00
05/02/16        7000.00
05/02/16        9000.00
05/02/16        7000.00
05/02/16        7250.00
```

Please solve it.

Comment: please post in what you have attempted, the queries that did not work, maybe sombody will point out your mistake

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`.

```
select t.* from
(
    select pur_Date as Date, pur_value as Value
    from purchase
    union all
    select sale_Date as Date, sale_value as Value
    from sale
)t
order by t.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
(SELECT pur_Date, pur_value FROM purchase)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Date, Value FROM Sale)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `Union All` query and sort by another assumed string `Date` by key `as`:**

**SQL>**

```
 select pur_Date as Date, pur_value as Value
 from purchase
            union all
 select sale_Date as Date, sale_value as Value
 from sale
            order by 1;
```